# How to check if an imageview has a specific type of image

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am downloading a file, by pressing on an imageview with a (download) icon. After downloading the icon changes to a (checked) icon.

How can I check if the imageview is showing the checked icon to prevent another download.

My current approach which hasn't worked:

```
if (holder.imgFileAttachment.getDrawable() == context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.downloaded)) {
      //Prevent another download
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just have a Boolean flag ? Set it when image is downloaded ..

Comment: If you use an image library like `Glide` then I believe caching of this sort is done for you. Otherwise, you can create an [`LRUCache`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache), and only download the image if it isn't already present in the cache

Answer (score 0):

From further research, after using [getDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#getDrawable()) I was able to get the data that it contains using [getConstantState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getConstantState()) from the `Drawable` class.

**Solution:**

```
if (imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState() == context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a).getConstantState()) {
    //contains image a
} else {
    // contains another image
}
```